# Developing iPhone and iPad separated app versions

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I've read a lot of posts about setting an Xcode project to develop a universal iOS app, but I couldn't find how should I proceed if I want separated apps instead: can I set two targets (one for iPad and another for iPhone) in the same Xcode project? Could I share the common logic code between the two versions that way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this, its quite simple you have to create two xib files for iphone and ipad separately. Then keep the file owner same View contoller class.You have to just check the device

```
 if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
      //iphone
    }
  else
   {
      //ipad
    }
```

Comment: After creating project ,go to target right click make the duplicate of the target, this will create new .plist file. Give the initial target name for iphone and duplicated target name for ipad.Then click on target and summary change target type for iphone and another target type to ipad. This will help u to create separate ipa for iphone and ipad.

Comment: Thanks, and then building the app for one of the targets will consider only the xib files and resources for such target?

Comment: Yes if you create ipa for each target will consider xib files and resources for each target separately.

Comment: So, if I understand... there is no difference at development stage between a universal project or separated versions, apart from having one or two targets? Can you have common logic anyway?

Comment: You just have functionality of the project same logic same just the UI change according to iphone and ipad.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if specifying two targets is necessary. Try setting the bundleID appropriately for the iPhone version, specify the appropriate distribution certs, build and submit. Now swap-in the bundleID for the iPad version, specify appropriate certs and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

YES you can set two targets (one for iPad and another for iPhone) in the same Xcode project, and YES you can share the common logic code between the two versions that way !

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to convert to universal app in a future having developed for separated targets, and viceversa?

Comment: YES it be possible, just add the iphone .xib to iPad target